# Node class for binary tree. Getting stackoverflow error

Tags: java, data-structures, nodes

Im getting a Stackoverflow error in my node class for a tree data structure. I am aware of the cause, however I cannot seem to fix it.

```
public class Node {
    Node right;
    Node left;
    String element;
    Node parent;

    public Node(){  
        right = new Node();
        left = new Node();
    }
}
```

because Im constructing new Nodes within the constructor, I get a stack overflow. How can I structure my constructor and avoid this error?

Comment: Um, don't do that? What *do* you want the values of `left` and `right` to be when you say `Node node = new Node();`?

Comment: I see where you got confused. Just leave left and right to be null. You can initialize there values as `new Node()` later when you decide to actully add a Node to your tree :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the Nodes on demand when they actually exist.

```
public class Node {
    Node left, right; // created as required
    String element;
    Node parent;

    public Node(Node parent, String element) {
        this.parent = parent;  
        this.element = element; // if you don't have an element you don't need a Node.
    }
}
```

Note: most likely you don't need the `parent` field, most implementations don't use it.

```
public class Node {
    Node left, right; // created as required
    String element;

    public Node(String element) {
        this.element = element; // if you don't have an element you don't need a Node.
    }

    public void setLeft(Node left) { this.left = left; }
    public void setRight(Node right) { this.right = right; }
}
```

e.g.

```
 Node d = new Node("d");
 d.setLeft(new Node("a"));
 d.setRight(new Node("z"));
```

Comment: I am just curious. You said the parent field is not implemented a lot. If a node is implemented with out parent how do you determine if a node has  or is a parent? Also how do you determine the root node?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson typically you start with the root of the tree rather than a random node within it. Starting at the root you know every node under it has a parent and what it's parent is.

Comment: Sadly, I didn't pay much attention in my data structure class when I was learning to program and I never went back to master these concepts. I think I get it now. This is a simple node that can be used to implement other ideas like Simple Linked List, Doubly Linked List, or Circular Linked List.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Each data structure has a Node which has the fields which are appropriate for that data structure. None of those structures need a `parent` field either.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson! I am going to go back and master data structures.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the recursive constructor calls as follows.

```
    public Node(){  
        right = null;
        left = null;
    }
```

The assembly of a specific tree should be done by assigning the children from perhaps outside the class or via getter and setter functions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `new Node` itself in its constructor, it'll never end till stackoverflow or heap out of memory, you could do it:

- Pass `left`, `right` to constructor:

Code:

```
public class Node {
    Node right;
    Node left;
    String element;
    Node parent;

    public Node(Node left, Node right){  
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

- With `setter`:

Code:

```
public class Node {
    Node right;
    Node left;
    String element;
    Node parent;

    public Node(){  
    }

   public void setLeft(Node left) {
       this.left = left;
   }


   public void setRight(Node right) {
       this.right = right;
   }
}
```